# fprintf vectors side by side and name each

Tags: matlab, vector, display

i got a problem with using disp to display 3 different vectors side by side. My output is as follows:

```
 1.8601    4.0025    4.8918
 3.8949    2.0025    4.8662
 2.1541    1.6125    1.4036
 3.2573    5.3038    3.2280
 5.4745    3.0017    3.5468
 4.8826    4.6000    1.9313
 7.3062    5.5444    4.4598
 8.8391    7.6922    5.7983
```

Now i want to name each column like:

```
dN1 = 1.8601      dN2 = 4.0025      dN3 = 4.8918
      3.8949            2.0025            4.8662
      2.1541            1.6125            1.4036
      3.2573            5.3038            3.2280
      5.4745            3.0017            3.5468
      4.8826            4.6000            1.9313
      7.3062            5.5444            4.4598
      8.8391            7.6922            5.7983
```

I tried to use `disp([dN1,dN2,dN3])`, but i wonder how i can print these "dN1 =" at the very first line and how i can seperate the vectors by a certain number of spaces.

I'm very grateful for any help.

Comment: You probably should print the first line separately and include the variable names in the string format and then loop over the rest of the rows with enough spaces in the format to make sure that the spacing stays the same. If you're fine with having your varible names on top of each column, that's a lot easier; call `disp()` with your variable names and then output the matrix as you did before, or consider using the [`table` type](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/table.html), which inherently displays it as such.

Comment: Thank you, this fixed it quiet decent! I did it with table and disp() now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Grouping the variables under a single table would let you leverage the native table display style

```
disp(table(dN1,dN2,dN3))
```

Output:

```
     dN1       dN2       dN3  
    ______    ______    ______
    1.8601    4.0025    4.8918
    3.8949    2.0025    4.8662
    2.1541    1.6125    1.4036
    3.2573    5.3038     3.228
    5.4745    3.0017    3.5468
    4.8826       4.6    1.9313
    7.3062    5.5444    4.4598
    8.8391    7.6922    5.7983
```